# Installed indicators not showing up

Tags: indicator

I have installed a couple of indicators from the [The OMG! Ubuntu! Guide to the best indicator applets around](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/01/the-omg-guide-to-must-have-indicator-applets/).

For some reason, however, none of them are showing up besides the sound, e-mail and Dropbox indicators, which were already there.

Any ideas?

Comment: Guess you rebooted or at least restarted gdm....And you added the indicators to the panel, didn't you? Just checking the obvious, if you don't mind.

Comment: I did reboot and I have the Indicator Applet on my panel, yes. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think they are regular programs that you have to start manually or make them auto start when you login.

Answer (score 1):

hasen_j is right. i had the same problem and figured out that it's a regular application indeed. To try, just hit alt+F2 and type Indicator on the laucher, you'll see your available indicators, start one and it'll appear in the indicators area. put it on the startup applications if you want them to start on ubuntu startup. :)